# Where to locate the App_Data folder in an MVC solution divided in 3 projects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a solution divided in 3 projects:

- Domain
- Web User Interface
- Unit tests

In my web.config, I defined my database like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="EntityFrameworkDbContext" 
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQL2008;Initial Catalog=MvcLearning;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=MVCLearning;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|MVCLearning.mdf;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Instance=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

We have the |DataDirectory| used in my connectionstring.

Everything about the database should be located in the 'domain' projet, right? But when executing the solution for the first time, the database is created and I see that it is created in the WebUI\App_Data folder...

I thought it should be located in the App_Data in the **'domain'** projet, shouldn't?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything about the database should be located in the 'domain' projet, right?

Ideally it should be located in a data access layer which should be a separate layer of your application than your business/domain layer.

> I thought it should be located in the App_Data in the 'domain' projet, shouldn't?

No, since the hosting project is the ASP.NET MVC application, things like App_Data are special folders which have only sense in a web application. So when you define `|DataDirectory|MVCLearning.mdf` in the web.config of your web application that really means the `App_Data` folder of the web application.

Answer (score 0):

In domain project you have your business logic and entities. But if you use |DataDirectory| it is placed in App_Data. Your domain project has nothing to do with where data file is stored.

Comment: thank you for your response. I understand. So, is it a good way of storing the database in the WebUI project (where I have my views & controllers)?

Comment: I don't put it there. I create it on SQL Server instance. But attaching may be the way to go on some servers that you don't own.